# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'screen.orientation.lock')

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Am trying the Unit test in m-generator. I injected $scope in test spec file, but am facing this error how to resolve this error.
I inject some files after came the same different inject the error.

controller file :

```
'use strict';
(function () {
 angular.module('main').controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);

 HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$log', 'SignOut', '$state', '$cordovaNetwork', 
'$auth', 'CommonService', '$scope', '$ionicPopup', 'Analytics', 
'BackupServices', '$translate', '$ionicPlatform'];
 function HomeCtrl ($log, SignOut, $state, $cordovaNetwork, $auth, 
CommonService, $scope, $ionicPopup, Analytics, BackupServices, 
$translate, $ionicPlatform) {
$log.log('HomeCtrl got called');
var vm = this;

vm.password = {
  input: '', // by user
  strength: ''
};
vm.grade = function () {
  var size = vm.password.input.length;
  if (size > 8) {
    vm.password.strength = 'strong';
  } else if (size > 3) {
    vm.password.strength = 'medium';
  } else {
    vm.password.strength = 'weak';
  }
};
vm.grade();

function activate () {
  screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
  Analytics.trackPage('Home-Page');
} })();
```

This is karma test js file I injected homectrl but homectrl have some plugins while test code did execute

test spec file:

```
 describe('module: main, controller: HomeCtrl', function () {

 beforeEach(module('main'));
  beforeEach(module('ngHtml2Js'));

 // instantiate controller
 var HomeCtrl;
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl',{ $scope: scope });
})); 

 describe('.grade()', function () {

it('should classify asd as weak', function () {
  HomeCtrl.password.input = 'asd';
  HomeCtrl.grade();
  expect(HomeCtrl.password.strength).toEqual('weak');
});

it('should classify asdf as medium', function () {
  HomeCtrl.password.input = 'asdf';
  HomeCtrl.grade();
  expect(HomeCtrl.password.strength).toEqual('medium');
});

it('should classify asdfasdfasdf as strong', function () {
  HomeCtrl.password.input = 'asdfasdfasdf';
  HomeCtrl.grade();
  expect(HomeCtrl.password.strength).toEqual('strong');
 });
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the path of screenorientation js file in your karma config path

'plugins/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/www/screenorientation.js'